# getData array is empty

Tags: flutter

I don't understand why my sharedPreferences doesn't save my data. `chance` is a list where I have data. I did a print before I have some data in `chance`. But when I return in this function I have null when I do `getData`. I think `sharedPreferences` does not keep my save.

```
void readFile() async {
  SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});
  sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  List<String> getData=[];
  getData = await sharedPreferences.getStringList('defis');
  print(getData);
  //Here is alway null

  if (getData != null && getData != "") {
    print(getData);
  }else{
    print('A');
    await sharedPreferences.setStringList('defis', chance);
    print('B');
    getData = await sharedPreferences.getStringList('defis');
    print('C');
    print(getData);
    //After print I have any Data
  }

}
```

Comment: did you print chance before insert in setStringList , maybe it is null?

Comment: I found the problem I remove SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});